# ¿Qué significa un "quote==false" dentro de print?

Tags: r

¿Qué significa un "quote==false" dentro de print? Por ejemplo:

```
print(c('La diferencia de meses es:',f), quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Hola Carolina, bienvenida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 1):

La ayuda de R es muy detallada, pero lamentablemente solo está en inglés. Si en la consola haces `?print` podemos ver que al respecto del parámetro `quote`:

> logical, indicating whether or not strings should be printed with
> surrounding quotes.

Es decir, en caso de `quote=TRUE` se agregan dobles comillas al principio y al final. Ejemplo:

```
> print("Hola", quote=TRUE)
[1] "Hola"
> print("Hola", quote=FALSE)
[1] Hola
```